# JPA enumerated entity with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, many-to-many

I have two entities with many-to-many relationship. My database structure:

```
Document    Status                  Document_Status
╔════╗      ╔════╦══════════╗       ╔═════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║      ║ id ║  status  ║       ║ document_id ║ status_id ║
╠════╣      ╠════╬══════════╣       ╠═════════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║      ║  1 ║ STORED   ║       ║           1 ║         1 ║
║  2 ║      ║  2 ║ APPROVED ║       ║           2 ║         1 ║
║  3 ║      ╚════╩══════════╝       ║           3 ║         2 ║
╚════╝                              ╚═════════════╩═══════════╝
```

And I want to use enum for Status.

```
public enum Status {
    STORED, APPROVED
}

@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // ??
    private Set<Status> statuses;
}
```

I've tried to implement it this way, but the solution ignores Status table and tries to create statuses from status_id in EnumType.ORDINAL way:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Status.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "Document_Status", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id"))
@Column(name = "status_id", nullable = false)
private Set<Status> statuses;
```

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) also doesn't help. It starts to find value with name "1" in Status enum.

I could wrap the enum into entity like recommended [here](https://coderanch.com/t/441705/databases/practice-mapping-collection-enum). But isn't it possible to be implemented without creation of wrapper entity?

Comment: Your database structure is fix?

Comment: No, it isn't. I just want to store enum values as strings to avoid problems in case the enumeration is changed. And don't want to directly store the strings in Document_Status to avoid duplication. If you know how to refactor the structure and satisfy the requirements, I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should edit your Entities to be like that

**Status**

```
@Entity
public class Status {

    public enum StatusEnum {
        STORED, APPROVED
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private StatusEnum status;
}
```

**Document**

```
@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Status> statuses;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But isn't it possible to implement without creation of wrapper entity? Don't we have a "magic" annotation to declare one more join?

Comment: @Raild I don't think so, you need ManyToMany relation so u have to create the wrapper

Comment: isn't it necessary to specify JoinTable for your solution?

Comment: @Raild No it's not, if you tried my solution it will work fine with you

Comment: I've got java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. But it works if I add:
@JoinTable(name = "Document_Status",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="status_id"))

Comment: Actually i am using same as in my answer in the project i am working on now, and it's working fine with me, anyway this is not a big problem, the main thing is have it working in whatever solution. :)

Comment: Yep, I mentioned it for someone who will be discovering the answer in the future. I'll choose the solution, if nobody propose one without extra entity within couple of days. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I later change the `StatusEnum` in code, will the status values in the join table get updated automatically?

Comment: No, in that case I think you must run SQL commands manually on your table to change the enum values to the new ones

Answer (score 1):

You need only a wrapper, if you will a join table and identify the enumy by id. You do not need this all.

```
Document    Status            

╔════╗      ╔═════════════╦═════════════╗ 
║ id ║      ║ Document_id ║  statuses   ║ 
╠════╣      ╠═════════════╬═════════════╣ 
║  1 ║      ║  1          ║ STORED      ║   
║  2 ║      ║  2          ║ APPROVED    ║ 
║  3 ║      ║  2          ║ STORED      ║ 
║  4 ║      ║  3          ║ APPROVED    ║ 
║  5 ║      ╚═════════════╩═════════════╝ 
╚════╝                        


public enum Status {
    STORED, APPROVED
}

@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;


    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Status> statuses;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that status string values are duplicated. If I decide to rename one of them I will have to update all respective rows. 
Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: I'm afraid so. The answer for my question is that with my requirements + JPA I have to deal with wrapper.